# Convert 3D Angle/vector (not position) to 2 angles (Angle, Pitch)

Tags: 3d, trigonometry, angle

I'm mapping/modding mostly in old game named Doom 2, but in port, while scripting i encountered a problem with angles in 3D world.
[screenshot of model with this problem. Note: Red points are the real and correct normal angles, and the Arrows are my attempt to convert these real 3D angles to doom's angle and pitch but failed and only facing up or down but not right or left...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPj0r.jpg)
For example i have here a MD3/Model/3D Model of some object and i wanted to show his mesh's vertices normals to point where exactly they facing (normal's real correct angle). But i've only managed (probably) to get only a Pitch Angle (or Z angle), by "Angle" i meant when it rotates 360 degrees to left or right, There is also "Roll" Angle in game but i don't think its important.

What i was trying to do is to convert from Real 3D Angle to Doom's Angle and Pitch, but i don't know anything mostly in trigonometry and it's formulas... I think its very easy for who knows in these things.

NOTE:
real 3D angle values are from -1 to 1 float.
doom's angle are from 0 to 360 float, and pitch from -90 to 90 float.

Here is my code of converting to doom's angle and pitch (up and down, left or right angles):

```
vector3 ConvertAngletoDoomAngle(vector3 ang) {
    return (
        0,      //angle (this one i have problem with, i want to make arrows turn correctly left and right)
        0,      //roll (this is not important and i bet it's harder to get...)
        90 * ang.z          //pitch (where arrows points down and up was looking kinda correct...)
    );
}
```

i think there are "cos" and "sin" needed to convert angle to 2D angle... i dont know :(
goal: these arrows must be facing to red points.

Comment: Are you asking about a cartesian to [spherical coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates) transformation? You need to define how `angle` and `pitch` are defined, and also which way is `xyz` directions in your world. Also what is `Real 3D Angle` mean?

Comment: i didnt get at all about "cartesian", but about spherical most likely yes. angle is which rotates left and right 360 its like look from above in 2D games where player rotates by one angle, THATs is angle, and pitch is when it looks up or low with limit degree from 90(up) to -90(down). Real 3D Angle is vector taken from real mesh's vertex in float value from -1 to 1 (-180 to 180 degrees probably), i showed in screenshot on link where Red points are normal correct angles by these float values (from -1 to 1) i just spawned them by offsetting them from original vertex's position by its angle value

Comment: x - angle, y - roll, z - pitch. https://puu.sh/HweKS/95cf6ced08.jpg also pls if possible i dont get anything when its in formula type text, but i will do in code/algorythm type text.

Comment: i dont try nobody to sort it out, just would need some little hints..

Comment: I still don't understand what the `x`, `y` and `z` components of `vector3 ang` represent. Typically the mesh defines the normal direction at each node as cartesian `xyz` values that is normalized as `√(x^2+y^2+z^2)=1`. Unless you know exactly what the inputs are, and you communicate it in the question, there is no way to effectively answer.

Comment: yes i understand, im really confused too im apologize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are given is the surface normal vector **n**, the components of describe the direction of the vector in terms of a cartesian coordinate system **xyz**.

[image: fig1]

and you want to find the azimuth angle **φ** about the *xz* plane, and the inclination **ψ** above the *xz* plane.

These are described first as a rotation about the *y* axis and then a rotation about the rotated *z*' axis

[image: fig2]

This sequence results in

```
nx = cos(φ)
ny = sin(φ)*sin(ψ)
nz =-sin(φ)*cos(ψ)
```

The way to reverse the process and find the angles is as follows

```
φ = atan2(-nz, sqrt(nx^2+ny^2))
ψ = atan(ny/nx)
```

where `atan2(dy,dx)` is the full quadrant arc tangent function, and `atan(r)` is standard arc tangent function.

Comment: I updated (corrected) the math above. Now the axis directions are consistent with the rotations.

Comment: you are the best ^^